# ASP.NET MVC/Web API model binding item to collection

Tags: c#, extjs, overloading, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am using Web API as the entry points for an ExtJS data store, where autosync is enabled in batch mode. This means that my defined Web API method can either be called with just 1 item or a collection of items, as described below.

Case with only 1 item:

```
{  
 "Category":"fsf",
 "Importance":10,
 "TaskNo":5467,
 "Id":"UnplannedTask-6",
 "StartDate":"2015-09-21T03:00:00+02:00",
 "EndDate":"2015-09-21T05:00:00+02:00",
 "Cls":"",
 "Name":"",
 "ResourceId":"18"
}
```

Case with multiple items:

```
[  
  {  
    "Category":"haer",
    "Importance":10,
    "TaskNo":5,
    "Id":"UnplannedTask-5",
    "StartDate":"2015-09-21T04:00:00+02:00",
    "EndDate":"2015-09-21T06:00:00+02:00",
    "Cls":"",
    "Name":"",
    "ResourceId":"14"
 },
 {  
  "Category":"fsf",
  "Importance":10,
  "TaskNo":5467,
  "Id":"UnplannedTask-6",
  "StartDate":"2015-09-21T03:00:00+02:00",
  "EndDate":"2015-09-21T05:00:00+02:00",
  "Cls":"",
  "Name":"",
  "ResourceId":"18"
  }
 ]
```

This is causing some issues for my Web API, as I have noticed overloading is somewhat tricky (perhaps impossible).

Here is the Web API action that accepts a list of items:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<dynamic> Update(IEnumerable<Appointment> appointments)
  {
   ...
  }
```

Here it is once more in the scenario that it only accepts one:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<dynamic> Update(Appointment appointment)
  {
   ...
  }
```

Now, both actions work individually. When only one item comes back, the model binding is correct. Same story for when a list is sent back. So far so good.
It is however impossible to know whether 1 item or 10 items will be sent across the wire. So I have to be able to suppport both actions, but overloading doesn't work in this way I have experienced - which means I can only use one action at a time.

So I was hoping for a solution where I could use model binding to convert the binding for 1 item to a collection of items, so that I can use only 1 action that accepts a list of items. Is this possible and are there any examples (and time savers) available?

Comment: use a JObject as the input parameter and then parse the data based whether it is an array or not.

Comment: As I suggested, I would consider this as the last resort. Parsing such JSON objects is error-prone and isn't really flexible. With the slightest change in data, this would break immediately. I'd rather go for the out of the box model binding capabilities, but I'm not quite sure if this is possible with the Web API.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but here is an article I wrote for webapi and extjs.  http://peterkellner.net/2013/03/13/using-sencha-extjs-4-2-sencha-architect-2-2-add-crud-to-rest-client-for-calling-microsoft-webapi-server/

Comment: @PeterKellner thanks for the tip, but apart from advertising your own blog post, this post has no significance to my question. Could you perhaps elaborate or suggest anything based on your knowledge about the topic?

Comment: sorry hbulens   I'm not sure how to solve your problem.  I've often struggled with the magic side of webapi trying to figure out what it is doing in terms of matching incoming parameters with no luck.  Often, I just take whatever comes in (I forget the syntax for that) and parse it myself in code to figure out the best plan.  I also try and get my client to always send arrays (even for 1 record) but it sounds like that is not a possibility here.

Comment: Your last sentence made me look for this setting in ExtJS, and it appears it is possible to always enforce arrays. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Kellner, I have investigated this issue and it appears there's a configuration setting in ExtJS's data store writer config that enables my request:

```
 proxy: {
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        create: '/api/Appointments/Add',
        update: '/api/Appointments/Update',
        destroy: '/api/Appointments/Destroy'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        allowSingle: false                 <------------------ That did the trick
    }
},
```